# Null string crashes Swift conditional

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, swift, nsnull

I have a `String` property as part of a custom object.  When I try to access the `String` on the custom object (when it's Null), the program crashes.

I can tell that the string is of type `NSNull` by printing out the custom object.

Every time I try

`if theString == nil
if theString == NSNull()
if theString.isEmpty`

the program crashes with `[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

What I don't understand is where it's trying to call `length`.  I would imagine it only calls `length` on the `isEmpty` function, but it crashes on the other two conditionals as well.

I'm thinking it could be because the custom object is created in objective-c with an `NSString`, but this also crashes when I try to convert the `String` to an `NSString`, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the underlying error is that the pointer to `NSString` is set to `NSNull` in Objective-C. `NSNull` should only be used to add empty values to collections like arrays or dictionaries. For plain object pointers you should use `nil` instead which will get translated to Objective-C as expected.

Comment: Right you are!  Thanks!  I figured it might be something like that, but why do Swift and Obj-C interpret NSNull differently?

Comment: They don't. Obj-c is dynamically typed. This means you can assign NSNull to a string if you want, but if you try to call a method on that string, you should end up with 'unknown selector' You really shouldn't set an NSString  to NSNull. Oh and it probably tries to call length because then implementation of equals for strings checks lengths.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like answering my own questions, but for what it's worth, if an Obj-C property is `NSNull` and you attempt to unwrap it in Swift, it will give you an error.

I fixed this by doing a check on my custom object (in Obj-C model), and if a property is `NSNull` then you set that property equal to nil like so:

```
if (theString == (id)[NSNull null]){
     theString = nil

}
```